# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs React-native react-native-braintree-dropin-ui

Tags: android, react-native, braintree

[com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.18.0] /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b902ab2fd2441da2151e11505f5b7f02/jetified-braintree-3.18.0/AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-45 Error:
Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.18.0] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-45
[com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.18.0] /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b902ab2fd2441da2151e11505f5b7f02/jetified-braintree-3.18.0/AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-64 Error:
Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.18.0] AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-64
[com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.18.0] /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b902ab2fd2441da2151e11505f5b7f02/jetified-braintree-3.18.0/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this tool https://www.dunplab.it/web-app-manifest-generator, use it for generate a easy manifest, with a UI and after can put it in your web app.
this will avoid you some errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not a web app, it's react-native android app

Comment: No matter the Manifest format's is same, try pls

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same error, I think it might be related to creds in the SDK repository, they don't work anymore.

Comment: I fixed by an update classpath